# Does mass has any influence on a horizontal launch?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-fall

Really short doubt. Let's say I have 2 objects, with masses 3kg and 4kg, both are thrown horizontally with the same initial velocity, both will touch the ground at the same time right? Because g affects equivalently to all masses, g is constant, therefore both will fall at the same time?

Separate bonus question: if those 2 masses 3kg and 4kg are thrown horizontally with different initial velocity, the mass won't affect either on this situation right? ie I won't have to use 3kg and 4kg at any moment to find the time where both touches the ground, right?

Comment: Yes nothing is different from a vertical fall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes acceleration due to gravity is same for all objects irrespective of their mass. So in both case, time the objects touch the ground will be same unless their is any initial velocity in that direction.

Comment: Two object with same initial velocity and subjected to same acceleration will have same trajectory and flight time (ignoring air resistance).  But energy required to impart same initial velocity to objects with different masses will be different.

Comment: This is only true if both are launched **from the same height* and at the same angle WRT horizontal.